# What are the JARs required for Hadoop project at startup?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, mapreduce, hadoop2

This must seem like an idiotic question but I am new to Hadoop and was trying to run a simple example. However, I keep running into problems with JAR files and dont seem to have the correct imports. I am using cloudera CDH 4 and it has a hole lot of JAR files to choose from with several versions of each. Since I am just starting off am not being able to differentiate.  Presently i am getting this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/configuration/Configuration
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<init>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:38)
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.DefaultMetricsSystem.<clinit>(DefaultMetricsSystem.java:36)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$UgiMetrics.create(UserGroupInformation.java:120)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.<init>(JobContextImpl.java:72)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:144)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.<init>(Job.java:139)
at com.ayon.hadoop.firstimpl.Driver1.main(Driver1.java:23)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 9 more
```

It is probably because of a wrong JAR file import. So my question is this:

Can anyone tell me what are the basic JAR files needed to start up a simple Hadoop job? Also any pointers to the above exception will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To include all the necessary jar files, compile your code  using the following command:

```
# javac -cp `$HADOOP_HOME\bin\hadoop classpath` YourClassFile.java
```

Please note the quotes

Comment: thanks. and if i am using eclipse shall i just include $HADOOP_HOME in my classpath?

Comment: In Eclipse go to the build path then add external jars to the project. $HADOOP_HOME/share/ path contains several folders (commons, hdfs, mapreduce) add jar files from these folders.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse, follow below steps to add JARs to your project

```
1.Right click on the project
2.Go to Properties
3.Click on "Java Build Path"
4.Libraries Tab
5.Add External JARs
6.Select the path "/usr/local/hadoop"
7.Select all "JAR files" & add all JARs
8.Again "Add EXternal JARs"
9.Go to path "/usr/local/hadoop/lib"
10.ADD all JARs in there
11.Click "Ok"
```

You're set. Hope this helps.. again it depends on the Eclipse version you're using.